# How to append a row with a vector column to a data frame in R

Tags: r

Here is an example,

```
df <- data.frame(x = I(list(1:2, 3:4)))
x <- df[1,]
```

Now the following does not work,

```
    df[2,] <- x
```

or

```
    df[2,] <- I(x)


 Warning message:
  In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 2, , value = list(1:2)) :
  replacement element 1 has 2 rows to replace 1 rows
```

How do I add more rows to data frame with a single column of vector type.

Comment: `df[1,]` is a list.  What exactly do you want the result to be?

Comment: I would like to add more 'list' rows to the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following after few tries,

```
df[2,] <- list(x)
```

add new row of list type.

Comment: That's a nice one, didn't `df[2,][[1]] <- x` work too?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are using a list. If you set your data frame as:

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 4)))
```

then your code should work:

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 4))) # Make DF
x <- df[1,]
df[2,] <- x

print(df)

> df
  X1 X2
1  1  2
2  1  2
```

Comment: I am trying to add a 'list' column. Your suggestion adds scalar values.